# How to get current timestamp UTC as unix timestamp using chrono crate

Tags: rust

I need to get the current timestamp UTC as UNIX timestamp using the package chrono
I am using the following version of chrono

```
chrono = { version = "0.4.22", default-features = false }
```

The code

```
use chrono;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", chrono::offset::Local::now());
    println!("{:?}", chrono::offset::Utc::now());
}
```

But Im getting the following error

```
4 |     println!("{:?}", chrono::offset::Local::now());
  |                                      ^^^^^ could not find `Local` in `offset`
```

How to get current timestamp UTC as UNIX timestamp using chrono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `default-features = false`, you need to enable the `clock` feature for `now()`:

> ##### [Features](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/#features)
>
> Chrono supports various runtime environments and operating systems, and has several features that may be enabled or disabled.
>
> - ...
> - `clock`: Enables reading the system time (`now`) that depends on the standard library for UNIX-like operating systems and the Windows API (`winapi`) for Windows.